# Passar array como parâmetro para web api em php com angularjs

Tags: php, angularjs, array, http, get

No meu ambiente local uso o PHP7 e desenvolvi API Restful para uma aplicação que usa AngujarJS. Precisava fazer um requisição get para a Api e passar um array como parâmetro e fiz dessa forma

```
$http.get("/Api/MinhaUrl.php", {
    params: {
        "Nomes[]": ["João", "Maria"]
    }
})
.then(function(response){ //dispara ao realizar requisição com sucesso
    console.log(response.data);
}, function(response){ //dispara ao falhar
    console.log(response.statusText);         
});
```

No meu arquivo MinhaUrl.php eu imprimi os parâmetros na tela da seguinte forma:

```
<?php
   print_r($_GET);
?>
```

Quando executado foi imprimido no console do navegador exatamente o que eu esperava, assim:

```
Array
(
    [Nomes] => Array
        (
            [0] => João
            [1] => Maria
        )

)
```

Até aqui nenhum problema. Porém, quando subo essa aplicação no servidor, que só suporta até a versão 5.6 do PHP (não sei se isso tem relação com o problema mas acredito que sim), o parâmetro com o array é recebido pelo PHP de outra forma, e o que é impresso no console do navegador é o seguinte:

```
Array
(
    [Nomes%5B%5D] => Maria
)
```

Ele "entende" os sinais de [] pelos códigos HTML deles %5B e %5D, pega somente o último elemento do array e o interpreta como uma variável comum.

O que devo fazer para ler os parâmetros no servidor da mesma forma como leio no ambiente local?

Answer (score 0):

So passar em formato de array, tu quase acertou, mas precisa repetir o nome do parametro.

`seu-endpoint?nome[]=João&nome[]=Maria&nome[]=BruxaMa`

ai sim la no PHP o seu `$_GET['nome']` vai ser um array

Answer (score -1):

```
$http(
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/items',
  params: {
    id: JSON.stringify(ids) // ids is [1, 2, 3, 4]
  }
)
```

Está ai, da forma que a variável `ids` é um array. Espero ter ajudado!

Answer (score -5):

```
JSON.stringify(["nome":"maria","nome":"joao"])
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).